# Export Google Maps Result Query

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting multiple pin locations for "XYZ store" by searching on maps.google.com

I want to export all the coordinates or points to whatever file possible (KML, HTML, doesn't really matter).

The final purpose of my need, is to create a custom map comparing XYZ Stores VS Foo Stores.

I already have my own KML of Foo Stores. But the challenge is when trying to export the XYZ Stores from the Google Maps search results, I can't find a way.

Any suggestion to attack this problem with another approach is more than welcome.

Comment: You need to create a custom map and add them to it, then once they're added you can download the KML.  https://mapsengine.google.com/map/

Comment: Yes, I know I need to add them to a custom map. But, I want a fast way to retrieve the locations after my search query @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 . I'm even looking for the maps api but I'm not good at it